# Unexpected-High-Level-Exception in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am working on project called as Google Places and Maps which shows the current location and nearby places.
I added the four jar files:-

```
1.android-google-maps-api11.jar
2.google-api-client-1.10.3-beta.jar
3.google-http-client-1.10.3-beta.jar
4.google-play-services.jar
```

Its is working fine during build-gradle but throwing exception while running the project
here is what i am getting

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices6587Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run                     command:
C:\Users\abhi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --        no-optimize --output        C:\android\sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\PlacesandMaps\app\b    uild\intermediates\dex\debug --input-       list=C:\android\sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\PlacesandMaps\    app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
2
Output:
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define           Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1 mins 25.598 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

And here is my Build.gradle in which dependencies are there

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.example.abhi.placesandmaps"
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 21
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
release {
minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-                rules.pro'
}
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.10.3-beta.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.10.3-beta.jar')
compile files('libs/android-google-maps-api11.jar')
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't juse jar files from Google. Use the new aar files. Here is the bug:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
```

There you include the play services twice remove the jar line.

The first line in your dependencies (`compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`) will include the jar a second time, so remove the jar file from your libs directory too.

In general I'm not sure what the other jars do, but I guess they are part of the play services.

Comment: Ya I removed  compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar') from dependencies but still showing the same result,now my dependies contains    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.10.3-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.10.3-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-google-maps-api11.jar')
   }

Comment: I am referring the article http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/ in this they have developed the project in eclipse but I am using Android Studio please help me which Jar files that i have add to my android studio project